# Where does .env (which contains the client secret) go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-server, authentication, environment-variables, oauth

I have a React app with a Node.js server.

Here is the directory structure:

**.env**
app
    **.env**
    .gitignore
    build/
    node_modules/
    package copy.json
    package-lock.json
    package.json
    public/
    README.md
    server
        **.env**
        node_modules
        package-lock.json
        package.json
        server.js
    src
        App.css
        App.js
        Cognito.js
        Page.js
        Login.js

You'll notice that .env is in multiple locations. These are my guesses as to where it could go. Perhaps it should not go in any of these locations.

The app will be built and uploaded to a private GitHub repo which AWS Amplify has access to. AWS Amplify then gets the files from the repo and allows the website to run.

Here is a part of server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const jwkToPem = require('jwk-to-pem');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

dotenv.config(); // Load environment variables from .env file

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET;
[...]
const base64Credentials = Buffer.from(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`).toString('base64');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is running!');
});

// Route to verify Cognito token
app.post('/verifyToken', async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.body.token;
    try {
        const jwks = await axios.get('https://cognito-idp.us-[region].amazonaws.com/[region and pool ID]/.well-known/jwks.json');
        const pem = jwkToPem(jwks.data.keys[0]);
        jwt.verify(token, pem, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, (err, decodedToken) => {
            [...]


app.post('/exchangeCode', async (req, res) => {
    const { code } = req.body;
    [...]
    try {
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('code', code);
        params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
        params.append('redirect_uri', 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard');

        const response = await axios.post('https://auth.[real domain].com/oauth2/token', params, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': `Basic ${base64Credentials}`
            }
        });

        // Log the response data for debugging
        console.log('Token Exchange Response:', response.data);

        res.json(response.data);
    } [...]
```

And part of Cognito.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUserPool } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

// Initialize Cognito User Pool with environment variables
const USER_POOL_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_USER_POOL_ID;
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID;

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID,
    ClientId: CLIENT_ID
});

const CognitoContext = createContext();
const exchangeCodeForTokens = async (code) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/exchangeCode', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ code })
        });

        [...]

export const CognitoProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const code = urlParams.get('code');
        if (code) {
            exchangeCodeForTokens(code).then(email => {
                setIsLoggedIn(true);
                setEmail(email);
            }).catch(err => {
                setError(err.message);
            });
        }
    }, []);

    const handleLogin = () => {
        const user = new CognitoUser({ Username: username, Pool: userPool });
        const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({ Username: username, Password: password });

        user.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: (session) => {
                setIsLoggedIn(true);
                // Fetch email attribute after successful login
                user.getUserAttributes((err, attributes) => {
                    [...]
```

I am thinking:

- AWS Amplify lets you set environment variables through the Amplify Console, so the .env should not be uploaded to GitHub even though the repo is private.
- The contents of the .env or may not be the same between directories.

Comment: Roughly speaking: when you have a better method to manage secrets and populate environment variables than storing them inside the application's `.env` files ; use that better method. - When you don't have such a better method, don't "hide" your configuration settings deep inside the directory tree that makes up your code. Maybe also read something like https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786 but your question might be more on topic for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic